# xrdp not connecting on centos 8, how to fix that?

Tags: vnc, centos8, xrdp

I have used below steps on my cloud machine.

1. Allowed all ports on azure machine(No security for testing).
2. Installed GUI.

   sudo dnf groupinstall "Server with GUI"

installed xrdp and vnc.

```
sudo dnf install epel-release
yum install xrdp tigervnc-server -y 
sudo systemctl enable xrdp --now
```

Added exception:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=3389/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Added a configuration:
/etc/xrdp/xrdp/ini added below line at the end.
**exec gnome-session**

When I connect to mstsc from windows, the xrdp window is coming. Once I enter credentials, it is just closing.

[image: RDP connection screen]

If I entered a wrong password, it will show this screen.

[image: error screen]

But if I enter correct credentials, it is just closing without any error message.

```
[root@localhost ~]# xrdp -ns
logging configuration:
        LogFile:       /var/log/xrdp.log
        LogLevel:      4
        EnableSyslog:  1
        SyslogLevel:   4
[20210106-11:50:31] [INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 7483
[20210106-11:50:31] [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
[20210106-11:50:31] [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
[20210106-11:50:31] [ERROR] trans_listen_address failed
[20210106-11:50:31] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:0)
[20210106-11:50:31] [ERROR] xrdp_listen_main_loop: xrdp_listen_get_port failed
[root@localhost ~]# xrdp -ns
logging configuration:
        LogFile:       /var/log/xrdp.log
        LogLevel:      4
        EnableSyslog:  1
        SyslogLevel:   4
[20210106-11:55:48] [INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 7733
[20210106-11:55:48] [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
[20210106-11:55:48] [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
[20210106-11:55:48] [ERROR] trans_listen_address failed
[20210106-11:55:48] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:0)
[20210106-11:55:48] [ERROR] xrdp_listen_main_loop: xrdp_listen_get_port failed
```